# Multi monitor setup reverts to clone after login on Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, xorg, kubuntu, multiple-monitors

When I boot up my computer and it gets to the logon screen, the display actually spreads across the two of them like I would expect.  Once I login it reverts to each monitor cloning the other and the desktop is no longer stretched across both of them.  Once I get going I can go into the Nvidia settings and set the displays to stretch again but the settings aren't persistent.

Here's my /etc/X11/xorg.conf

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 331.20  (buildd@roseapple)  Mon Feb  3 15:07:22 UTC 2014


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "HYO DUAL-DVI"
    HorizSync       88.8 - 88.8
    VertRefresh     60.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 650 Ti"
EndSection

Section "Screen"

# Removed Option "metamodes" "DVI-I-1: 2560x1440_60 +2560+0, DVI-D-0: 2560x1440_60 +0+0"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-I-1: nvidia-auto-select +2560+0, DVI-D-0: 2560x1440_60 +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

How do I get the settings to persist through logging in?

It looks like this question might be a dupe of [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11421/after-startup-display-reverts-to-one-desktop-duplicated-on-both-screens) but that one was closed as too localized for reasons that I can't figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using nvidia settings on Kubuntu? The KDE settings do it great. 
Remove your xorg.conf completely, reboot, and go to KDE System Settings - Display configuration.

If settings do not persist, try setting them to mirror, reboot, and change again. Make sure that you do not have some leftover configs or scripts from your previous attempts. Especially, check at "Startup and Shutdown" "Background services" that KScreen is running.

Finally, there is a "rude way". Disable KScreen maybe. Look up your monitor names by typing `xrandr` in console. Then run a configuration command like

```
xrandr --output "VGA1" --primary --mode 1920x1200 --output "HDMI2" --right-of "VGA1" --mode 1920x1200
```

If it helps, just put it in autostart somewhere.

Comment: How is that? I think it is exactly the answer to the question.

Comment: This didn't work.  The xorg.conf at least made the login screen appear correctly.  By removing it, the login screen was continuous but the right and left screens were swapped.  After logging in, the screens were still swapped.  I used the KDE system settings to switch them to be correct and did another restart.  After the restart the setting did NOT persist.

Comment: Try new suggestions.

Comment: Could you give me a hint as to what leftover configs and scripts I should look for?  This is a pretty new install so I haven't mangled with anything except xorg.conf.

Comment: I meant configs that you have changed. For example, you should not have created `xorg.conf` as a whole. It is outdated. Better not to use at all.

Answer (score 1):

NVIDIA has fixed many issues and improved their drivers a lot since the release of drivers 331.
So install the latest NVIDIA drivers supporting GTX 650 Ti from **Proprietary GPU drivers** PPA.

Before you install new drivers uninstall all NVIDIA related software you have installed before.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

When the **GRUB boot menu** appears : Highlight the **Ubuntu menu entry** and  press the "**e**" key.
Add the **nouveau.modeset=0** parameter to the end of the linux line ... Then press **F10** to boot.

Now install the latest current stable NVIDIA drivers from the short-lived branch by executing :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-355 
sudo reboot
```

In case you are using a notebook with a hybrid graphics solution install Optimus support as well.

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime
```